# MariaDB 10.0.4 different mysqlclient reported

Tags: mysql, php, mariadb, phpinfo

I use MariaDB-server 10.0.4 on my CentOS 6.4 64-bit server.

PHPMyAdmin shows: libmysql - 10.0.4-MariaDB

While phpinfo shows: Client API version    5.3.12-MariaDB

Why I got two versions ? How to change Client API version to 10.0.4 ?

I got MariaDB-shared from 10.0.4 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove all libs inside /usr/lib64/mysql then it worked :)

Only /usr/lib64 can stay.

Comment: What?  You should probably file a centos bug.